# Jackson error shown in the ToolTwist Designer

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jackson, tooltwist

Whenever my widget gets placed on a page in the ToolTwist Designer, the following error was shown. The error does not happen in other applications I am developing, but started when I tried to connect to Amazon web services.

```
Stack trace:
com.dinaa.DinaaException: Error calling DesignerUIM.op_showEditPane():
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode.asText()Ljava/lang/String;
    at tooltwist.wbd.GenericMustacheWidget.toObject(GenericMustacheWidget.java:173)
    at tooltwist.wbd.GenericMustacheWidget$2.<init>(GenericMustacheWidget.java:163)
    ...
```

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is usually caused by the Amazon AWS library aws-java-sdk, which includes the Maven dependencies jackson-core-asl (1.8.9) and jackson-mapper-asl (1.8.9).

The GenericMustacheWidget uses jackson-support (0.6.3) which requires newer versions of these libraries (1.9.2).

The solution is to exclude these libraries in the POM where you defined your dependency on aws-java-sdk:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

AWS seems to work fine with the newer versions of the Jackson libraries. Restart the server, and your page should render correctly.